# Py2Exe error caused by pywinauto on some systems: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CUIAutomation"

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, pywinauto

I'm rolling out an EXE to several Windows 2012 R2's and the majority of them work just fine. However, seemingly under the same condition, I have a handful that spit out the error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CUIAutomation'

I used to just have:

```
from pywinauto.findwindows import find_window
from pywinauto.win32functions import SetForegroundWindow
```

And I tried also adding in:

```
import pywinauto
```

But that didn't do much. I also attempted to change the code so instead of using `find_window` I used the full `pywinauto.findwindows`. Same for `SetForegroundWindow`.

My import list. Sorry if it's sloppy or redundant, I'm new and self-learning.

```
import requests
import json
import os
import winshell
import sys
import re
import subprocess
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con
import os.path
import ctypes
import fnmatch
import urllib2
import shutil
import psutil
import pywinauto
from pywinauto.findwindows import find_window
from pywinauto.win32functions import SetForegroundWindow
from pathlib import Path
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from stat import S_IREAD, S_IRGRP, S_IROTH
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Really the only place I'm using pywinauto in my script is:

```
SetForegroundWindow(find_window(title_re = r'Server*'))
```

py2exe error on launch for some systems:

```
File "SVMon.py", line 17, in <module>
File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dm1p2f\PyInstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
File "site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dm1p2f\PyInstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
File "site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <module>
File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dm1p2f\PyInstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
File "site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dm1p2f\PyInstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
File "site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 47, in <module>
File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dm1p2f\PyInstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
File "site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 181, in <module>
File "site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 169, in _build_pattern_ids_dic
File "site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 50, in __call__
File "site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 63, in __init__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CUIAutomation'
[1928] Failed to execute script SVMon
```

Comment: Seems like if I just rename my script and recompile it that it works. Why is that? Any insight?

Comment: This might be comtypes cache that contains auto generated Python wrapper around UIAutomationCore.dll. You can do “pip uninstall comtypes” and try again.

Comment: You need comtypes if using backend=“uia” in find_element(), so this is not the case.

Comment: I ended up fixing this by using PyInstaller and I'm not exactly sure what did the trick but I added every hidden import I could think of:

pyinstaller —hidden-import comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient —hidden-import comtypes —hidden-import comtypes.gen —hidden-import comtypes.patcher —hidden-import comtypes.GUID —hidden-import pywinauto —hidden-import pywinauto.CUIAutomation —hidden-import pywinauto.findwindows —hidden-import pywinauto.findwindows SVMon.py —onefile —clean

Comment: Great. You can post it as an answer and accept it. It's OK to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using PyInstaller and I'm not exactly sure what did the trick but I added every hidden import I could think of:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient --hidden-import comtypes --hidden-import comtypes.gen --hidden-import comtypes.patcher --hidden-import comtypes.GUID --hidden-import pywinauto --hidden-import pywinauto.CUIAutomation --hidden-import pywinauto.findwindows --hidden-import pywinauto.findwindows VPSMonitor.py --onefile --clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade pip install comtype=1.1.7 It will work- if not downgrade it and again upgrade it to the latest one