# "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CUIAutomation"

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, pywinauto, comtypes

Hello I've similar problem like this:

[Py2Exe error caused by pywinauto on some systems: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CUIAutomation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56910153/py2exe-error-caused-by-pywinauto-on-some-systems-attributeerror-module-obje/)

with py2exe and also pyinstaller I get error:

`AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient' has no attribute 'CUIAutomation' [15964] Failed to execute script SVGWalker`

Without py2exe or pyinstaller the script is running without errors !!

Here my startup python code:

```
#################################################################
# Version String
#################################################################
__version__ = "1.4.1.0"





#import WindowHandler
#import win32com.client
#import pywinauto
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import timings
from pywinauto import ElementNotFoundError
from pywinauto import Desktop
#import comtypes.client # 02.10.2020
import glob
import time
import sys
import os
import argparse
import traceback
import helper
import XmlManifest
```

and the error: with line 13 above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SVGWalker.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pywinauto import application
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 47, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 181, in <module>
  File "pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 169, in _build_pattern_ids_dic
  File "pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 50, in __call__
  File "pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 63, in __init__
AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient' has no attribute 'CUIAutomation'
[5732] Failed to execute script SVGWalker
```

Nothing in the thread above helped me.

Is there any other hint or solution

Comment: Is it possible to add your code?

Comment: ###############################################################################
# Version String
###############################################################################
__version__ = "1.4.1.0"





#import WindowHandler
#import win32com.client
#import pywinauto
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto import timings
from pywinauto import ElementNotFoundError
from pywinauto import Desktop

Comment: Error:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SVGWalker.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
......
AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient' has no attribute 'CUIAutomation'

Comment: better to add code to the question via editing.

Comment: I'd suggest to try installing `comtypes` from master branch: `pip install https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/archive/master.zip`

Comment: Hello Vasily Ryabov, sorry master branch does not help.

Comment: My solution is: 1. pip uninstall comtypes 2. Using pyinstaller instead of py2exe 3. call: pyinstaller.exe --hidden-import comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient --hidden-import comtypes --hidden-import comtypes.gen --hidden-import comtypes.patcher --hidden-import comtypes.GUID --hidden-import pywinauto --hidden-import pywinauto.application --hidden-import pywinauto.findwindows --hidden-import pywinauto.findwindows [myMainPythonFile].py --onefile --clean

Comment: But this is not a good solution :-(

Comment: I recently updated to comtypes from 1.1.11 to 1.1.12 and this returned.